# Paypal PayFlow Pro Asp.Net configuration

Tags: asp.net, paypal, payflowpro

So, this does not necessarily have to do directly with the code itself, although it is certainly a component of it.

I recently downloaded and installed the PayFlow Pro SDK for use with ASP.net

link here: 
https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/library_download_sdks

I installed this to my development machine. I also came accross this example code which I figured outlined the primary setup for basic Paypal Credit Card Transaction functionality.

link here:
http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/PayPal_PayflowPro.aspx

Anyways, I have two main questions

- Do I have to install the SDK on the web hosts server in order to utilize the functionality of it? This seems to make sense, however, the tutorial in the second link suggests I create a web reference. Unless I am not understanding something here, wouldn't this just strictly work on my development machine, or at least, the functionality of the remote website that references this web reference to access the sdk, would this not be dependent on my computer running and broadcasting this information?

I just need clarification on how to install and/or access the sdk for use on a remote webhosts server (ie. do i need to install the sdk on the web-hosts server and if so, how would one go about doing so (ie. where to install, how to install)?).

- Are there any other clean cut examples like my second link provides, that sort of outline the basic functionality of Payflow Pro? I find paypal's examples numerous and convoluted and their online slides/video tutorials to be tedious.

Perhaps I should just get off my lazy ass, but I have found peers from the general community to be much more informative in a way more efficient manner, so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: And could you please mention how did you solve it? I am also in need of getting through it at the moment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For anyone interested, after enough searching I found a great example that notified me of all the fundamental processes to creating a basic transaction and allowed me the knowledge to further manipulate the sdk.

Check it -

[Code Projects PayflowPro example and introduction.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152280/Online-Credit-Card-Transaction-in-ASP-NET-Using-Pa)

Comment: The example does not show  PCI compliance payment page option (e.g., credit card page hosted by PayPal).